# (Visual Studio) Why C# class/properties are hidden in Auto-Complete, but visible after typing?

Tags: visual-studio, autocomplete

There are some classes, that are not shown up when typing. But after you type it and put dot, then it is well recognised class. Why? how to force VS (2019) to show them in beforehand?

[image]

Comment: What VS version do you have? Also, from my experience when this happens, it means that I can't use those classes or objects from the current context I'm in.

Comment: @JavierSilvaOrtíz v2019

Comment: Sorry for the delay, time-zone and work. I haven't updated from 2017 but like I said, whenever that happened to me it meant that I couldn't use those classes or objects from the current context I was in.

Comment: @JavierSilvaOrtíz thanks for response and taking time at all... 
well, in my case all of those cases (i have frequently) i am able to use those objects without problem even after compilation and in run-time. Just VS doesnt show.

Comment: Well, in VS2015, I encountered a relatively similar bug, sometimes IntelliSense didn't worked at all, had to close the file (not VS) and reopen it again. Maybe posting your question at VS support forums would help. It's a very weird behavior, if I had to bet, I'd say it's a bug. If you ever find out, let me know, or better yet, auto-answer your question, you'd get my vote (and another badge :-) ).

Comment: @JavierSilvaOrtíz haha, i will see if i find any solution,.,